# How to get xticks to work with Matplotlib bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, graphing

When running the code below:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')
jsonfile = 'data.json'

with open(jsonfile, 'r') as f:
    histogram = json.load(f)

labels = []
y = []
y_norm1 = []
y_norm2 = []
for resolution in histogram:
    if resolution[0][:3] == 'Dup':
        labels.append(resolution[0][-11:])
        y.append(resolution[1])
x = []
N = len(labels)
ind = np.arange(N)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1 = axarr[0]
x = plt.xticks(range(len(labels)),labels)
ax1.set_title('Duplicate')
ax1.bar(x,y,color='b',align='center')
```

I get the error:

> "incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 2 or scalar."

I am attempting to display results of analysis but am running into this error when trying to use the string labels I had embedded into my json file.

The reason I'm using subplots is because there is a comparison being made between two different plots; if I replace the

```
x = plt.xticks(range(len(labels)),labels)
```

with

```
x = np.array(range(len(labels))
```

I am able to view my results.

Edit:

If instead of:

```
x = plt.xticks(range(len(labels)),labels)
```

I use

```
x = ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(labels)), labels)
```

I get the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'XTick' and 'float'

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set the xticks for an axis instead? For example `ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(labels)), labels)`

Comment: Tried this, it gave me the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'XTick' and 'float'" when calling bar.